# Cannot add CSS class to my CharField with .widget.attrs.update

Tags: python, django, widget

I'm learning django widgets documentation
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/
I created new class like in sample:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField()
```

And then tried to add CSS class to name:

```
name.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})
```

But django crushes and VSCode sends me error:
Class 'TextInput' has no 'attrs' member

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you show the *full* traceback of the error. There might be a different problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the error message says "**Class** 'TextInput' has no 'attrs' member".

You are trying to modify a widget class. Attributes are only available once the widget class is instantiated:

```
form = CommentForm()
form.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})
```

If you want to add the attribute to all forms, you can do that like this:

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'})
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField()
```

**Edit:**

Updating as part of the class definition works too (although I'm not quite sure why you would want to do that).

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField()
    name.widget.attrs.update({'foo':'bar'})

>>> form = CommentForm()
>>> form.fields['name'].widget.attrs
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Looks like it works but how can i modify it inside my class like name.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'special'})?

Comment: Actually, I double checked and that should work, please see my update. If it doesn't please post the complete code and the full traceback, as Willem requested.

Comment: from django import forms

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'some-class'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField()
    name.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'some-class-2'})

Comment: I have instantiated widget and still have an error when trying to modify it

Comment: There is something really strange going on here. Please edit your original post to include the full stacktrace